# AJAX function parameter is null?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, frontend

i got a problem with JS:

On line 1 to 4 I take all "a"-Elements from the DOM and get their hrefs.
later I want to reload the URL via AJAX, but the href does not arrive correctly... Whats wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
       ajaxReload($(this).attr('href'));
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function ajaxReload(href) {

var xmlhttp = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", href, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(xmlhttp.readyState != 4) {
            document.write('loading');
        }
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert('hello');
            //alert('getting '+xmlhttp.status+' for '+href);


            var pureHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var ajaxstart = pureHTML.indexOf('<!-- AJAX START -->');
            var ajaxend = pureHTML.indexOf('<!-- AJAX END -->');
            var ajaxContent = pureHTML.substring(ajaxstart, ajaxend);

            var writeContent = document.getElementById('content');
            writeContent.innerHTML = ajaxContent;

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the href doesn't arrive correctly?

Comment: at the bottom part the function gets HTML Code from the file referred in the var 'href', but if i output it in an alert 'href' returns null..

Comment: You have jQuery available. Is there **any** reason why you don't use the AJAX functions jQuery provides?! If you need a plaintext response, you can use `dataType: 'text'`.

Comment: Yes, I just started learing js, I wanted to know whats behind this fancy jquery-stuff.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I've misunderstood your code. I *think* that you simply need to (at least approximately) just remove code as commented below:

```
//$('a').click = function(href) {

    var pureHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var ajaxstart = pureHTML.indexOf('<!-- AJAX START -->');
    var ajaxend = pureHTML.indexOf('<!-- AJAX END -->');
    var ajaxContent = pureHTML.substring(ajaxstart, ajaxend);

    $("content").html(ajaxContent);

//  ajaxReload(href); //this would cause a loop?

//  return false;
//}
```

To answer your later question - you can change your event propagation handling to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
       ajaxReload($(this).attr('href'));
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And for the further comments, maybe try changing your:

```
document.write('loading');
```

To:

```
$("content").html(xmlhttp.status); //so now you can see the loading status for testing
```

Comment: ...not! Where do I have to put the return false;?
I put it on the top so the link in the DOM will not be executed, but the Script stops then.

Comment: You could put event.preventDefault(); in the click function next to where you call ajaxReload. Or return false in the same place.

Comment: hmm, both ways dont work, i tried to do put a return false in the click-event but the same thing happens..

Comment: The code as above should definitely work to stop the default click action happening. What issue are you experiencing?

Comment: ok now i got it, the click-event above works, but i dont get the function below the onreadystatechange, it keeps loading.

Comment: You don't get the rest of the function after the onreadystatechange bit? You might need to post a new question or edit the code in this one as I can't figure out what you mean...have you definitely removed the call to ajaxReload() that was in the onreadystatechange?

Comment: Added one tweak suggestion to my answer. Maybe you have an actual problem with getting the response (so I've suggested putting the response code instead of your loading text). Maybe you'll see a 500 there or something.

Comment: so, it works since i changed it - status is 200.. everything went better than excepted :)

Comment: Good stuff. Got there in the end! :)